# Lyx - how to create sections without titles

Tags: lyx

I'm currently looking into lyx because I'm starting to get fed up with writing LaTeX by hand. The problem is, LyX seems to be a bit opiniated about how sections should be written - I'm used to writing

```
\subsection{}
\subsubsection{}
...
\subsubsection{}
```

etc., because in the documents I'm writing I don't want titles for my sections. I just want them to be numbered. LyX doesn't seem to like that though, and ends up deleting my sections (and subsections, and subsubsections) when I don't have any text in their titles.

I can just insert a hard space, but this feels kind of weird. I don't understand why lyx wouldn't just let me hit enter and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to us a 'hard space' as title of the sections, through `<Ctrl>+<space>`, that should do the trick (it's the keyboard shortcut for LaTeX's "~").

Answer (score 0):

You can insert [Evil Red Text](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ERT#what) (raw LaTeX commands) in LyX. Look for `Insert` -> `TeX Code` menu. I just tried it and inserted `\subsection{}` inside the ERT, and it compiled successfully and showed the section numbers.